# How to integrate AWS SNS services into IOS APP?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I want to use AWS SNS services to send push notifications from server to IOS App. What are the steps i need to follow to integrate the SDK in the app and at the same time at the server side.I have read almost all the documentation and samples available in Github. But i see some files are missing in the samples like AWSRuntime.h,AWSSNS.h, i am not sure where to find.

A small tutorial with sample would be really helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: AWSMobileHub can help you create a custom sample app https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the tutorial on the AWS site for integrating mobile push notifications with AWS SNS? It has an option for APNS. I wasted a lot of time with the certificate stuff though. Through trail and error I learned that you must make sure that if you are using development credentials that you use APNS_SANDBOX as your platform, and if you are using the production credentials make sure to use APNS platform.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html

I am actually working through it at the moment. Good luck. I would love to hear if you get it working, I did get it to successfully use my credentials and send messages to my ios app via AWS Management Console, but the tutorial has yet to work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information...i am trying to create new app in the console and am sure that i am using the correct certificates .p12 exported from keychain access and selected APNS_SANDBOX, loaded credentials from file (Certificate and private key values), and clicked "Add New App" and it gives me "There was a transient failure registering the app with amazon sns. please try again"...Do we have any steps missing?? or is it the issue with AWS server. Would be really helpful if i can get steps to work this out. Thanks.

Comment: And also it seems IOS SDK V2 is in developer preview and in V1 i don't find any samples for SNS. Can you please direct me to the samples where i can find them.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need to integrate AWS SNS in your IOS app, because SNS is integrated server to server, however what you have to do in the IOS app side is getting APNS token pass it to your backend and then call SNS api to `createEndPoint`.